# SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User) method always returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.1

> Here the if condition is always returning false even when - app.useAuthentication() middleware is used
>
> _Layout.cshtml

```
                @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                {
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <form method="post" asp-controller="account" asp-action="logout">
                            <button type="submit" style="width:auto"
                                    class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0">
                                Logout @User.Identity.Name
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                }
                else
                {
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="account" asp-action="register">
                            Register
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="account" asp-action="login">
                            Login
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }
```

> Satrtup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EmployeeManagementPractice.Modals;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace EmployeeManagementPractice
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private IConfiguration _config;

        public Startup(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }
        
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication();

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();


        services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("EmployeeDBConnection")));

        services.AddMvc(action => action.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

        services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, SQLEmployeeRepository>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=home}/{action=index}/{id?}");
        });
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        });
        }
    }
}
```

> Whenever I run the mvc file in debug mode, the signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) is returning false even after correct Login Id and Password
>
> In the controller, in the Login Action- if (result.Succeeded) is returning true, Please help someone why signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) is returning false.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Login Password");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: how have you defined the `signInManager` in your `_layout` page?

Comment: @AakashBashyal  Yes I have injected that.......also in the debug menu even after correct id and password , signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) is showing false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the order of your `DbContext` and `AddIdentity`.  If you are not using any JWT Token I don't think you will need the configuration for `services.AddAuthentication();` I have removed that. and see the code below you have been missing a couple of things.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Add this two configuration
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
    ///////////////////

    services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("EmployeeDBConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
    }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()        
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc(action => action.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

    services.AddScoped<IEmployeeRepository, SQLEmployeeRepository>();
}
```

And in `Configure` change the following:

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
    }

    //and this thing are also needed
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    //you have not given the path to redirect after login, so u need to add this.
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

And in your `_Layout.cshtml` check, if you have used:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager
```

It seems all of the configurations you have used here is based on dotnet core 2.2. There is something different in asp.net core 3.1.

For further information please visit the link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: i already had injected the them in the layout....even though it is not working

Comment: have you changed the configuration services as I have modified?

Comment: can u update your all the code.....here....new updated and changed one.

Comment: sir I don't get that....can you give your email id so that I can send the screenshots also....I am not able to progress in my project due to that...Please sir